# jar works in classpath not in targetplatform eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, target, platform

I have a jar that is working fine in Eclipse in other peoples Eclipse environments here.
When I add it to mine, it does not get resolved but when I open target platform state, it is present there.

If I had add the jar to classpath as an external jar from the folder in the target platform, it resolves everything correctly and build is fine.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?  I've tried new target platform definition, new workspace, new Eclipse version etc...  I don't think it is an issue with the jar as it is working for the other people in my team.

Eclipse info:
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800

Anyone anything else I should try?

Comment: Going to add that the classpath etc... is all in source control and the manifest files for the projects.  The only thing not in source control is the target platform and the workspace.

Comment: Adding kind of redundant information but the jar is not in plugin-dependencies when I expand it out but is in the target platform state view in eclipse so it looks like for some reason it isn't picking up that this jar is required but does for other people in the team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved to linux environment and issue disappeared using Eclipse 3.8.1.